# can't store session value, using while loop to print row

Tags: php, session, while-loop

I am using while loop to print tickets for match as scheduled.
i want to store information in session but it is not working with while loop

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']='set';
  $_SESSION['teama']=$team1;
  $_SESSION['teamb'] = $team2;

  $query = "SELECT team1, team2, time, date FROM wb_match"; 
  $result = $db->prepare($query);
  $result->execute(); 
  $result->bind_result($team1, $team2, $time, $date);
  while($result->fetch()) {
    echo $team1.' - '. $team2.' - '. $date.' - '. $time. '<form method="post" 
    action="selectseat.php"><input type="submit" value="Buy now" name="buy"/></form>';
  }
?>
```

output

> arsenal - balton - 2014-03-15 - 18:00:00[Buy button]
>
> liverpool - Everton - 2014-03-17 - 10:00:00[Buy button]

on next page i am checking session continue and printing

```
<?php  
  session_start();
  $one = $_SESSION['teama'];
  $two = $_SESSION['teamb'];    

  if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    echo'not set';
  }
  else 
  if($_SESSION['name']=='set'){
    echo 'Session is set'. $team1;
    echo  $one, $two; 
  }
?>
```

print session is set and nothing else.

Comment: shouldn't  $team1 be $one ? $team1 is not defined

Comment: Is there a reason why you have <form> inside your loop? Also before you set the session where is $team1, and $team2 coming from?

Comment: yeah i am printing buy button in front of each match available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
while($result->fetch()) {
  $_SESSION['name']  = true;
  $_SESSION['teama'] = $team1;
  $_SESSION['teamb'] = $team2;
  echo $team1.' - '. $team2.' - '. $date.' - '. $time. '<form method="post" 
  action="selectseat.php"><input type="submit" value="Buy now" name="buy"/></form>';
}
```

But doing that will only store the last row into the session. So here is my suggestion.

First page will show all list of matches and buttons like:

```
// you might want to include the id that ids the match
$query = "SELECT id, team1, team2, time, date FROM wb_match"; 
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute(); 
$result->bind_result($matchId, $teamA, $teamB, $time, $date);
while($result->fetch()) {
    echo $teamA.' - '. $teamB.' - '. $date.' - '. $time. '
    <form method="post" action="selectseat.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="matchId" value="'. $matchId.'">
       <input type="submit" value="Buy now" name="buy"/>
    </form>';
}
```

`selectseat.php` will receive the posted match id then query for the data of that match.

```
$matchId = $_POST["matchId"]

$query = "SELECT team1, team2, time, date FROM wb_match WHERE id = ?"; 
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->bind_param("i", $matchId);
$result->execute(); 
$result->bind_result($team1, $team2, $time, $date);

// do stuff to your result
```

Comment: i have a button in front of each row. when i click that button i want to select seat for that specific match which is on that date team a vs team b. is there any other way to print tickets and process?

Comment: then maybe you want to have another query on your second file that now has a `WHERE` clause specific to the selected match. I think you are making your code complicated by using sessions for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: tried this and it is while loop like u did here in your ans. it prints only last row no matter what i select.

Comment: yes i will do query based on date of selected match. i want to query seats available of that date for this match and show green and red seats.

Comment: Like I said, it will only give you the last row.

Answer (score 0):

### Lets break it down

You don't get the output `not set` because `$_SESSION['name']` isset.

You then get the output `Session is set` because `$_SESSION['name'] == 'set'`.

Now here is where the problem is:

On your first page you set

```
 $_SESSION['teama'] = $team1;
 $_SESSION['teamb'] = $team2;
```

But at this point in time `$team1` and `$team2` are both undefined.

Only after you `$result->fetch()` are those variables populated.

After they are populated you need to update the value in your `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: on second page where i whote  '$one = $_SESSION['teama'];' i am storing teama to $one and printing it.

Comment: is there any other way to print all row from a table.

Comment: You can just keep adding to `$_SESSION['teama']` through every iteration of `fetch()` and it will all be there on the next page. I.E in your loop `$_SESSION['teama'] .= $team1 . ' ';`